# Querying with linq a collection mapped as a map (IDictionary)

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Using NHibernate, I have a collection of entities mapped as a dictionary.
By example, class A has a collection of B named `Children`, mapped as a `IDictionary<int, B>`. B has a property `Name`.

Querying class A base on some condition on B children unrelated to their dictionary indexation is quite straightforward with `HQL`:

```
from A where A.Children.Name = 'aName'
```

Runs flawlessly.

But for achieving the same with `LINQ`, this is quite less straightforward:

```
IQueryable<A> query = ...;
query.Where(a => a.Children.Values.Any(b => b.Name == "aName"));
```

Fails with message `could not resolve property: Values of: B`

So yes, we can trick it through

```
IQueryable<A> query = ...;
query.Where(a => ((ICollection<B>)a.Children).Any(b => b.Name == "aName"));
```

That does works and yields expected results.

But this looks to me a bit ugly, I would rather not have to do that 'invalid' cast (at least 'invalid' outside of linq2NH context).

Is there any better way for querying a children collection mapped as a IDictionary with Linq and NHibernate?

Comment: *Just a hint. I never use Dictionary. Only one-to-many and many-to-one, all items are first level citizens. Querying is much easier, and DB looks also good, because each table has its own surrogate key...*

Comment: @RadimKöhler, no impact on DB, children have their technical primary key, and an unique index on parent key + dictionary key (both composing its natural id), which would be there without that mapping too. So yes I could simply map that as a set, then use ToDictionary on it when needed. I would probably do that, if using map in my case ends up causing more complex code instead of easing it. But I would rather check prior to that I am not missing something on how to use it properly with linq.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an exercise, I have decided to extend [linq-to-nhibernate](/questions/tagged/linq-to-nhibernate) for supporting `Values`. This give a solution to the question.

There is many ways for extending linq2NH, see this [list](/a/11469134/1178314). Here, I need to add a new 'generator', as in my [answer to another question](/a/35492489/1178314).

First you need a bunch of `using`:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NHibernate.Hql.Ast;
using NHibernate.Linq.Visitors;
using NHibernate.Linq.Functions;
```

Then, implement HQL translation for `Values`.

```
public class DictionaryValuesGenerator : BaseHqlGeneratorForProperty
{
    public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(
        MemberInfo member, Expression expression,
        HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
    {
        // Just have to skip Values, HQL does not need it.
        return visitor.Visit(expression).AsExpression();
    }
}
```

Extend the default linq2NH registry with your generator:

```
public class ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry : 
    DefaultLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry
{
    public override bool TryGetGenerator(MemberInfo property,
        out IHqlGeneratorForProperty generator)
    {
        if (base.TryGetGenerator(property, out generator))
            return true;

        return TryGetDictionaryValuesGenerator(property, out generator);
    }

    private DictionaryValuesGenerator _dictionaryValuesGenerator = 
       new DictionaryValuesGenerator();
    protected bool TryGetDictionaryValuesGenerator(MemberInfo property,
        out IHqlGeneratorForProperty generator)
    {
        generator = null;
        if (property == null || property.Name != "Values")
            return false;

        var declaringType = property.DeclaringType;
        if (declaringType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var genericType = declaringType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
            if (genericType != typeof(IDictionary<,>))
                return false;
            generator = _dictionaryValuesGenerator;
            return true;
        }

        if (declaringType != typeof(IDictionary))
            return false;
        generator = _dictionaryValuesGenerator;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I had quite a hard time figuring out how to register a generic class property generator. There is built-in support for many cases including generic dictionaries methods through derived class of `GenericDictionaryRuntimeMethodHqlGeneratorBase`, but apparently no support for generic dictionaries properties. So I have ended up 'hard coding' it in the `TryGetGenerator` method for properties.

Now configure NH to use your new registry. With hibernate.cfg.xml, add following `property` node under `session-factory` node:

```xml
<property name="linqtohql.generatorsregistry">YourNameSpace.ExtendedLinqToHqlGeneratorsRegistry, YourAssemblyName</property>
```

Now this does work:

```cs
IQueryable<A> query = ...;
query.Where(a => a.Children.Values.Any(b => b.Name == "aName"));
```

<sub>Disclaimer: done only as an exercise, I have not even committed that in my actual code. I am currently no more using any `map` in my mappings. I have added some just for testing, then I have undone all.</sub>